How can I set layout to null in .net blazor?
I'm working on a Dashboard application using .NET Blazor WASM, where, except for the login page, all pages can share a same layout. So how can I specify for the login page that it doesn't need to inherit any layout?

specify a layout that is just @body

lol. good one. wonder why they don't make such an easy syntax for such a common requirement.

Technically you don't have to use a layout they are used by the Router Component.
